# How to make the TCheckBox's box area bigger?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a TCheckBox with a Font.Size of 40, Width is 400 and Height is 100. The box where the check is drawn is too small and I want it to be bigger. I played around with its property and I can't seem to find how to make it bigger.

I want the box area of TCheckBox to be adjusted.

Comment: Have you ever experienced this in any other Windows GUI program? Why should the end user have such a big box just because you think his desktop of 1024x768 px should be filled to 1/3 with one checkbox? Use [scaling](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/High_DPI) instead.

Comment: @AmigoJack, I want the box to be around 40x40 to 60x60 pixels. User is complaining they failed to notice the checkbox so I have to make it bigger. As much as possible, I don't want to make big UI change just because they failed to notice it.

Comment: Teach your users that a checkbox can also be ticked/unticked by clicking on its caption (or using [keyboard shortcuts/accelerator keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_shortcut) in general). Only in a bad/non-conforming UI users have to aim for the box.

Comment: I have a similar problem. My solution is to place the checkbox on a panel and change the panel colour to something really obvious.

Comment: Thanks guys for the response. I have manage to address my problem by creating a work-around. For the box-area I used a TImage and for the caption I used a Panel. So far it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Standard CheckBox component does not allow to do that. Only option will be to create custom style with big checkbox image and apply this style to your component. This is quite complicated to implement, and styles format can change with new version of Delphi, so you will have to update it.

Much easier will be to use component TJvgCheckBox from JVCL component suite. It is open source and free, and has separate properties to add checkbox pictures.

Comment: "Only option will be to create custom style". No, you don't need to use VCL styles. Owner drawing is much better. You can also easily create your own checkbox control.

Comment: I do not see any need to create yet another custom control when there is JVCL.